# OrderBy and Relation OneToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by, dql

I have a little problem:

Mod entity in relation OneToMany with View entity.

- Mod

  - View (views for one day)
  - View
  - View

I would like get the mods and sort them by number of views.
The problem is that with the code below, the sorting is incorrectly and ORDER BY m.views isn't working.

```
public function getWeeklyModsMostViewed($number = null)
{
    $query = $this->_em->createQuery(

    "SELECT m
     FROM KynaModsBundle:Mods m
     LEFT JOIN m.views v
     WHERE v.date > :dateLimit
     ORDER BY v.views DESC
    "
    )->setParameter('dateLimit', new \dateTime('-7days'))
     ->setMaxResults($number);

    return $query->getResult();
```

Can you help me please ?
Thanks.

Comment: you probably need to add `v` to the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can order a collection of object with the ORM annotation ( that you add in your entity )

> @ORM\OrderBy({"views " = "DESC"})

And you do your request like :

> SELECT m
>        FROM KynaModsBundle:Mods m
>        LEFT JOIN m.views v
>        WHERE v.date > :dateLimit